# Family visit to Disneyland Paris

Tags: budget, france, paris, family, disney

What is the cheapest way to get Disneyland Paris tickets for a family of 2 adults and a 9 year old kid around Easter?

Comment: Where would you be coming from?

Comment: A package could be cheaper, if you book travel + hotel + park tickets all together, have you checked those?